# Код для вывода произвольных полей ACF

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно составить код и реализовать вывод произвольных полей ACF. Если произвольное поле ACF mobile активно, то для мобильных устройств выводить только произвольные поля ACF 1,2,3,4, а для компьютеров только произвольное поле ACF 5. Если произвольное поле ACF mobile не активно, то для всех устройств выводить только поля ACF 1,2,3,4, а произвольное поле ACF 5 не выводить вообще.

```
<?php if ( get_field('mobile') ): ?>


<?php if(wp_is_mobile()) { ?>
  <?php произвольное поле acf 1 ?>

  <?php произвольное поле acf 2 ?>

  <?php произвольное поле acf 3 ?>

  <?php произвольное поле acf 4 ?>


<?php } else { ?>               
  <?php произвольное поле acf 5 ?>
<?php } ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ( wp_is_mobile() || ! get_field( 'mobile' ) ) {
    // произвольное поле acf 1.
    // произвольное поле acf 2.
    // произвольное поле acf 3.
    // произвольное поле acf 4.
} else {
    // произвольное поле acf 5.
}
```